# An other way to load a js file in js code

Tags: javascript, dom

I opened a javaScript file in a javaScript time....

```
document.write("<script src='newnote.js' type='text/javascript'></script>");
```

is there an other way to load the js in js code..?

(this file is for loading a popup menu js code , which is loaded after delay by clock js code ... so i want an othe way to loaded it)

Comment: By close, do you mean remove it from the page? The next logical question is why do you need to remove it?

Comment: You could remove the reference from the document to that resource.

Comment: Have you tried document.close() what happened

Comment: Above script gives javascript error quotes problem

Comment: @jjj: The reason everyone's so confused by what you are trying to do is that Javascript files aren't meant to be nor can be unloaded from the current page.  Even if you remove the reference to the file, all the script has already been parsed so everything remains in memory and is still accessible from other scripts or events.

Comment: this file is for loading a  popup menu js code , which is loaded after delay by clock js code  ...  so i want an othe way to loaded it .. and  enough with those minuses!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible that the script that you are adding to the page (in this case `newnote.js`) is causing the error you are experiencing?

Instead of the line you used starting with `document.write` use this instead:

```
var newnote = document.createElement('script');
newnote.src = "newnote.js";
newnote.type = "text/javascript";
document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild( newnote );
```

If you still get your quotes error, then the code inside of `newnote.js` is messed up.

Don't think this was really what you were asking, but if you used the code I listed above you could then remove this file from your page by calling this:

```
document.documentElement.firstChild.removeChild( newnote );
```

**One more thought:**

If your path to `newnote.js` is not correct (because it is not in the same directory as the calling page) then the server would return a `404` error page instead of the file. If your browser tried to execute it like javascript, it could throw an error. Try supplying the full URL: `http://yoursite.com/js/newnote.js` or a root relative one: `/js/newnote.js`

Comment: it cause an other prablim .... 
an my path is correct... 
but you are very good .. thaks for trying

Comment: Can you elaborate on the other problem that happened? This is the preferred way of loading a script onto a page.

Answer (score 6):

When opening a JS file, its code is executed at once - functions are created, code is run, events are set. The only way to 'unload' a Javascript file is to manually undo all the code that has been run as a result of loading the unwanted file: setting all new functions, variables and prototype aditions to `undefined` (e.g. `window.badFunction = undefined`, unset all events, remove all new DOM elements..

If you wanted to unload another JS file every time when opening a page, it could in theory be done, but not very easily and if the loaded JS file should change, you would have to update your invalidating file.

Answer (score 4):

What you did isn't like opening a local file in a programming language like C++ or Java.  You don't need to close anything.

Comment: what is happening as a result of not closing?

Answer (score 3):

you are not opening a javascript file, in fact you cannot open any file from local file system, so there is no question of closing. You are inserting a script tag replacing all contents of the document. This would result in fetching newnote.js using the current url with newnote.js replacing anything after last slash.

Answer (score 0):

To include a script you could try this:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = 'newnote.js';
s.type = 'text/javascript';
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
head.appendChild(s);
```

or like that:

```
document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='newnote.js'><\/sc" + "ript>");
```